# cmake linker error with library installed in custom path

Tags: cmake, linker

I have compiled and installed with CMake the library SDL_bgi to a custom prefix `/custom/prefix/`. This library uses SDL2.

Now I want to use it in another project with the structure below but I get a linker error when I compile with `make`:

```
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o  -o test  -Wl,-rpath,/custom/prefix/lib: /custom/prefix/lib/libSDL_bgi.so 

/usr/bin/ld: /custom/prefix/lib/libSDL_bgi.so: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: /custom/prefix/lib/libSDL_bgi.so: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
```

I have also written the file `cmake/modules/FindSDL_bgi.cmake` so that may be wrong as well.

If I compile with the following command I can compile correctly:

```
g++ test.cpp -I . -lSDL_bgi -lSDL2 -I /custom/prefix/include/ -L /custom/prefix/lib/
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Project structure:

```
cmake/modules/FindSDL_bgi.cmake
src/test/CMakeLists.txt
src/test/test.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

Libraries:

```
/usr/lib/libSDL.so
/usr/include/SDL.h
/custom/prefix/lib/libSDL_bgi.so
/custom/prefix/include/graphics.h
/custom/prefix/include/SDL2/libSDL_bgi.h
```

cmake/modules/FindSDL_bgi.cmake:

```
# - Try to find LibXml2
# Once done this will define
#  SDL_BGI_FOUND - System has LibXml2
#  SDL_BGI_INCLUDE_DIRS - The LibXml2 include directories
#  SDL_BGI_LIBRARIES - The libraries needed to use LibXml2

# Hardcoded for now
set(SDL_BGI_PATH
    /custom/prefix/
)

set(SDL_BGI_SEARCH_PATHS
    /usr
    /usr/local
    /opt
    ${SDL_BGI_PATH}
)

find_path(SDL_BGI_INCLUDE_DIR graphics.h
    HINTS
    $ENV{SDL2DIR}
    PATH_SUFFIXES include
    PATHS ${SDL2_SEARCH_PATHS}
)

find_library(SDL_BGI_LIBRARY
    NAMES SDL_bgi
    HINTS
    $ENV{SDL2DIR}
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
    PATHS ${SDL2_SEARCH_PATHS}
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

find_package_handle_standard_args(SDL_bgi REQUIRED_VARS SDL_BGI_LIBRARY SDL_BGI_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(programmi_kennedy)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules")

set(COMPAT_HEADERS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
)

find_package(SDL_bgi REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(src/test)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${SDL_BGI_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE ${SDL_BGI_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)
```

/custom/prefix/include/graphics.h:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_bgi.h>
```

Comment: So... do `find_package(SDL2)` and link with `${SDL2_LIBRARIES}`, you only link with SDL_BGI.

Comment: What is still not clear to me is why do I need to link against SDL2 and not just against SDL_BGI? My test.cpp only uses SDL_BGI directly, and SDL_BGI is already compiled and installed. Shouldn't the missing symbols be resolved at runtime somehow?

Comment: No they shouldn't. Because cmake will not know "how" or "to which" symbols exactly you want to resolved them. It's programmers job to resolve all dependencies. You can (and unit tests are done that way) write a custom mock implementation of SDL2 library and link with it. Or you can link with the system installed SDL2. Or you have SDL2 installed in a directory and you want to link with that. You have tell cmake about it.

Answer (score 1):

What I was missing is to link to `SDL2` with `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` and link to `SDL2::SDL2`. (I did try to link to `${SDL2_LIBRARIES}` but the syntax is different now). Thanks to @KamilCuk to point me to the right direction.

EDIT:

I changed the `FindBGI_sdl.cmake` module in order to search for the dependencies (`SDL2`) and link against them using the `INTERFACE` keyword. In this way the target `test` can link only against `SDL_bgi` and have the dependencies resolved automatically.

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE SDL_bgi::SDL_bgi)
install(TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)
```

cmake/modules/FindSDL_bgi.cmake:

```
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-Clause License.  See accompanying
# file Copyright.txt or https://cmake.org/licensing for details.

#[=======================================================================[.rst:
FindSDL_bgi
-------

Finds the SDL_bgi library.

Imported Targets
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

This module provides the following imported targets, if found:

``SDL_bgi::SDL_bgi``
  The SDL_bgi library

Result Variables
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

This will define the following variables:

``SDL_bgi_FOUND``
  True if the system has the SDL_bgi library.
``SDL_bgi_VERSION``
  The version of the SDL_bgi library which was found.
``SDL_bgi_INCLUDE_DIRS``
  Include directories needed to use SDL_bgi.
``SDL_bgi_LIBRARIES``
  Libraries needed to link to SDL_bgi.

Cache Variables
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The following cache variables may also be set:

``SDL_bgi_INCLUDE_DIR``
  The directory containing ``foo.h``.
``SDL_bgi_LIBRARY``
  The path to the SDL_bgi library.

#]=======================================================================]

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(PC_SDL_bgi QUIET SDL_bgi)

find_path(SDL_bgi_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES graphics.h
    PATHS ${PC_SDL_bgi_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

find_library(SDL_bgi_LIBRARY
    NAMES SDL_bgi
    PATHS ${PC_SDL_bgi_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

set(SDL_bgi_VERSION ${PC_SDL_bgi_VERSION})

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(SDL_bgi
  FOUND_VAR SDL_bgi_FOUND
  REQUIRED_VARS
    SDL_bgi_LIBRARY
    SDL_bgi_INCLUDE_DIR
  VERSION_VAR SDL_bgi_VERSION
)

if(SDL_bgi_FOUND AND NOT TARGET SDL_bgi::SDL_bgi)
  add_library(SDL_bgi::SDL_bgi UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(SDL_bgi::SDL_bgi PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL_bgi_LIBRARY}"
    INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${PC_SDL_bgi_CFLAGS_OTHER}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${SDL_bgi_INCLUDE_DIR}"
  )
  target_link_libraries(SDL_bgi::SDL_bgi INTERFACE SDL2::SDL2)
endif()

mark_as_advanced(
  SDL_bgi_INCLUDE_DIR
  SDL_bgi_LIBRARY
  SDL2_DIR
)
```

#### Useful references:

- https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-developer.7.html